# Power BI data to large to export from matrix visual component

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have a data set that contains ~4 million rows. The visual component I am using is a Matrix visual. After selecting the data I need, the Matrix visual is 150 rows and 25 columns. I would like to export this into a csv in the exact way it is shown in the Matrix. When I try exporting the data set via the export data option in the menu, I get a message indicating that my data set is too big.

Is there a way of exporting the data in this format, or perhaps a python / R script that can gain access to the data the visual is using?

Any help appreciated, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exporting data as is from a matrix, is not supported. However, it is planned and you can [vote for it](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/15164733-allow-table-and-matrix-data-exports-to-match-power), if you want to. You can only export the underlying data, but you obviously reached it's [limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-export-data#limitations-and-considerations).

What you can do, is to connect from Excel to your data source and create a pivot there, the same way as your matrix in Power BI.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using Tableau, it has this feature build in.